# Exception thrown by a thread in a third party library

Tags: c#, exception

I am using a third party library in my code.  One of the methods on the third party library is getting a thread from the thread pool and doing some work on it.  Unfortunately it is throwing an exception from its thread which I am unable to catch and handle because it is from a different thread.

I know that this exception is not going to cause the application any harm (it is not an out of memory exception or anything similar), so I'd like to log it and try the operation again later when it might succeed.

I am currently logging the exception by using the AppDomain UnhandledException event, but my application is still terminating. Is there any way I can catch this exception and handle it?

Answer (score 2):

Its really hard to catch exceptions across threads, in fact I think its impossible.

The only work around is to see if they third party library has a call back routine that can notify you of exceptions.

Check the docs/api for the library.

Comment: I had this issue with 0MQ which is a threading library. They were terminating instead of throwing the exception properly as well, so I would check the source of the library if its available.

Comment: +1. Not possible. You can use `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException` event to receive the exception. But it won't prevent the application from crashing. But you can atleast restart it from there. (`Process.Start()`)