# How to catch exception thrown by a task that's not awaited in a third party library?

Tags: c#, exception, async-await, task, topshelf

I have a Windows Service (using Topshelf) that relies on the third party library [EasyRedisMQ](https://github.com/jkruer01/EasyRedisMQ). Unfortunately, I just discovered the following code in one of the library methods:

```
    public async Task InitializeAsync()
    {
        if (SubscriberInfo == null) throw new NullReferenceException("SubscriberInfo is required.");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SubscriberInfo.SubscriberId)) throw new NullReferenceException("SubscriberId is required");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SubscriberInfo.ExchangeName)) throw new NullReferenceException("ExchangeName is required");
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(SubscriberInfo.QueueName)) throw new NullReferenceException("QueueName is required");
        if (OnMessageAsync == null) throw new NullReferenceException("OnMessageAsync is required");

        await _cacheClient.SubscribeAsync<string>(SubscriberInfo.ExchangeName, DoWorkAsync);

        DoWorkAsync("").FireAndForget();
    }
```

Here DoWorkAsync returns a task, but as FireAndForget indicates, this is unfortunately not awaited. Actually, FireAndForget is a method with an empty body (the only purpose is to make it explicitly that the task is not awaited).
See the full source code [here](https://github.com/jkruer01/EasyRedisMQ/blob/8a7f1b89c283cc86ced8fcfd3bc0eaa1419a06a4/Src/EasyRedisMQ/Models/Subscriber.cs).

The problem is that an exception occasionally is thrown in DoWorkAsync, which causes the service to crash:

```
{
  "Depth": 0,
  "ClassName": "StackExchange.Redis.RedisConnectionException",
  "Message": "SocketFailure on RPOP",
  "Source": "mscorlib",
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.StackExchangeRedisCacheClient.<ListGetFromRightAsync>d__67`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at EasyRedisMQ.Models.Subscriber`1.<GetNextMessageAsync>d__12.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at EasyRedisMQ.Models.Subscriber`1.<DoWorkAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at StackExchange.Redis.Extensions.Core.StackExchangeRedisCacheClient.<>c__DisplayClass59_0`1.<<SubscribeAsync>b__0>d.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore.<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_1(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.WaitCallback_Context(Object state)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)\r\n   at System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()\r\n   at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()\r\n   at System.Threading._ThreadPoolWaitCallback.PerformWaitCallback()",
...
}
```

I would very much like to catch the exception (as it's actually harmless and simply retry the operation). However, after reading [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12002903/exception-thrown-by-a-thread-in-a-third-party-library) and experimenting with AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FirstChanceException, I do not have high hopes.
The problem with FirstChanceException is that it occurs outside Tophelf's

```
HostFactory.Run(hostConfigurator => { ... }
```

method, in which I have the reference to the service (where the business logic resides):

```
hostConfigurator.Service<IConsumer>(serviceConfigurator =>
{
    serviceConfigurator.ConstructUsing(() => IocContainer.IocContainer.Instance.Resolve<IConsumer>());
    serviceConfigurator.WhenStarted(consumer => { /* Here I have control */ });
    ...
}
```

Has anyone any ideas on how to deal with this situation?

Comment: Looking at this code, something called with `FireAndForget` should never throw. So this could be a potential bug. Maybe you should file an issue.

Comment: Unfortunately the client library hasn't been updated for 2 years, so I'm not confident that filing a bug will help. But I completely agree that this should ideally be handled in the library itself.

Comment: I haven't any experience with `EasyRedisMQ`, but in the source given by you there is a call to `PushMessageToSubscriberAsync`, so there could be a way to subscribe to this message. It should be dispatched, even if there was an exception processing it.

Comment: Why not fork the repo and fix it to your liking? Maybe the author is still willing to accept PR's as well.

Comment: @Iqon it's a good catch! The problem is however, that the exception is thrown because of the line GetNextMessageAsync(), so it's outside any catch clause - hence it crashes my service.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to [event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) of TaskScheduler:

```
TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException += TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException;
//...

private void TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException(object sender, UnobservedTaskExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    e.SetObserved();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I actually looked into TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException too, but the problem is that I need to add some code to retry the operation, and in TaskScheduler_UnobservedTaskException I'm not able to invoke any method on the consumer object (specified in serviceConfiguration.WhenStarted(consumer => { ... });